# C++ добавление данных из struct в QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

Имеется `struct`

```
#ifndef WAYPOINTDATA_H
#define WAYPOINTDATA_H

struct WaypointData
{
    short iD;
    short iconId;
    double lng;
    double lat;
    double alt;
    int minAltitude;
    int state;    
};

#endif // WAYPOINTDATA_H
```

Данные в `struct` добавляеются через чтения `.json` файла.

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                    tr("Load"), "",
                                                    tr("File (*.wpf)"));
    if(!filename.isEmpty()){
        QByteArray val;
        QFile file(filename);
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
        val = file.readAll();
        file.close();
        QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val);
        QJsonObject obj = d.object();
        int i = 0;
        MapView->waypointData.clear();
        for(const QString &key: obj.keys() ){
            QString line = obj[key].toString();
            QStringList elements = line.split(",");
            double lng = elements[0].toDouble();
            double lat = elements[1].toDouble();
            double alt = elements[2].toDouble();
            WaypointData* w = new WaypointData();
            w->alt = alt;
            w->lng = lng;
            w->lat = lat;
            w->state = 0;
            QString id= key;
            w->iD = id.remove(0,8).toInt();
            MapView->AddWaypoint(*w);
        }
        MapView->DrawWaypoints();
    }
```

Есть также `QComboBox` - `WayPointBox`.

Интересует, как добавить данные из struct в QComBox в формате как на картинке ниже.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е получается - `w->iD[0], w->lng[0], w->lat[0], w->alt[0]`

Comment: QString::number совсем не работает? Пробовали делать конкатенацию двух и более строк? Что не работает то?

Comment: @test123 ui->WayPointBox->addItems(QString::number(w)); пробовал прописывать так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Грязный и быстрый способ**. Просто слепить все необходимые данные в строку, и добавить ее в комбобокс(если надо, исходную структуру тоже можно положить):

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(WaypointData)

//...

static const QString format("%1, %2, %3, %4")
WaypointData data;
ui->WayPointBox->addItem(format.arg(data.iD)
                               .arg(data.lng)
                               .arg(data.lat)
                               .arg(data.alt),
                         QVariant::fromValue(data));
```

---

**Красивый но чуть более сложный способ**. Сделать собственную модель:

```
class WaypointDataModel : public QAbstractListModel{
    QVector<WaypointData> _data;
public:
    WaypointDataModel(QObject *paretn):
        QAbstractListModel(parent)
    {
        //Как-то заполняем _data
        //Можно недостающие данные получить через параметры конструктора
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{
        switch(role){
            case Qt::DispalyRole:
            case Qt::EditRole:
                return _toString(_data[index.row()]);
            default:
                return QVariant();
        }
    }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const{
        if(parent.isValid()){
            return 0;
        }

        return _data.size();
    }
private:
    QString _toString(const WaypointData &waypointData) const{
        static const QString format("%1, %2, %3, %4");
        return format.arg(data.iD)
                     .arg(data.lng)
                     .arg(data.lat)
                     .arg(data.alt);
    }
};
```

Там где у вас должен заполняться комбобокс делаем так:

```
ui->WayPointBox->setModel(new WaypointDataModel(ui->WayPointBox));
```

При желании можно добавить методы доступа к данным в модели, сделать их редактируемыми, комбобокс разноцветным, можно подключить модель к десятку разных представлений, короче можно все что душе угодно. А главное, весь код отвечающий за данные сосредоточен в модели.

**PS** Код писал в браузере, могут быть ошибки

Comment: слегка изменил код под себя: `static const QString format("WP%1:  E: %2  N: %3  Z: 32  %4");
            ui->AuswahltWegPunkte->addItem(format.arg(w->iD)
                                           .arg(x)
                                           .arg(static_cast<int>(y))
                                           .arg(w->alt));` Подскажите пожалуйста, как теперь при нажатии кнопки "ОК" получать из выбранной строки только iD, x, y и alt?

Comment: @Insider, если бы вы сделали так как я сказал, то можно было бы так 
`ui->WayPointBox->currentData().value<WaypointData>().iD`. А после того как вы "слегка" изменили код, уж и не знаю.

Comment: @Insider, После объявления `WaypointData` напишите `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(WaypointData)`. И при вызове `addItem` вторым параметром передавайте вашу структуру. Тогда ее копия будет храниться в комбобоксе, и можно будет в любой момент получить к ней доступ через `currentData`

Comment: Если я сделаю как по  вашему коду, то получу совсем другие данные http://prntscr.com/i18ix7 .

Comment: @Insider, вы упорно игонрируете самую суть. Методу `addItem` нужно передавать **ВТОРОЙ ПАРАМЕТР**. Который вы благополучно выбросили.

Comment: Я не игнорирую саму суть http://prntscr.com/i18urd по вашему коду я получаю ошибку error: no matching function for call to ‘QComboBox::addItem(QString, WaypointData&)’
                                      data); поэтому и переделал в другое. Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(WaypointData) стоит в самом начале файла

Comment: @Insider, воо, с этого надо было начинать. Обновил ответ

Comment: Странно, но даже так, данные не верны http://prntscr.com/i1904n

Comment: я решил уже на основе своего кода. спасибо все равно.

Answer (score 1):

Просто конвертируем структуру в строку по вашему формату:

```
QString toStr(WaypointData *w) {
    return QString::number(w->iD)+", "+QString::number(w->lng)+", "+QString::number(w->lat)+", "+QString::number(w->alt)+";";
}
```

И набиваем список структур в бокс:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<WaypointData>> points;
//...

for(auto point = points.begin(); point!=points.end(); ++point)
    ui->WayPointBox->addItem(toStr(*point));
```

Прекрасно работает.

Comment: Получаю такие ошибки error: no matching function for call to `‘MainWindow::toStr(std::shared_ptr<WaypointData>&)’
             ui->AuswahltWegPunkte->addItem(toStr(*point));` и `error: non-member function ‘const QString toStr(WaypointData*)’ cannot have cv-qualifier` `const QString toStr(WaypointData *w);` прописал в `.h`
 const QString toStr(WaypointData *w) const {

Comment: @Insider, Исправил код. Уберите const.

Comment: + В хидере не рекомендуется писать реализацию/определение функций. Разве что, можете шапку оставить.

Comment: теперь выдает только ошибку тут  error: no matching function for call to ‘MainWindow::toStr(std::shared_ptr<WaypointData>&)’
             ui->AuswahltWegPunkte->addItem(toStr(*point));
                                                        ^

Comment: Я не экстрасенс, и считывать код из вашей головы не умею.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/i16moj ничего больше не стоит. в .h файле теперь QString toStr(WaypointData *w);

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71768/discussion-between-test123-and-insider).